# Retrofit api call returning old data.Not getting up to date data

Tags: java, android, retrofit

i am making a small app to connect with the server and i am new to retrofit.My code is as follows

```
MyRetrofit.java
----------------------------------
private MyRetrofit(){

        retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }
    public static synchronized MyRetrofit getInstance(){
        if (myRetrofit==null){
            myRetrofit=new MyRetrofit();
        }
        return myRetrofit;
    }
    public Api videoApi(){
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
```

and in my main activity added some code like

```
Call<List<usermodel>> call= MyRetrofit.getInstance().videoApi().getVideoData();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<usermodel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<usermodel>> call, Response<List<usermodel>> response) {
                userlist.clear();
               userlist=response.body();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(userlist.get(1).getFirst_name()+"Size "+ userlist.size()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //adapter=new VideoAdapter(videoLists,getApplicationContext(),viewPager);
               // viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<usermodel>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
```

When i run this i got the correct values from the api.Then for a test i changed the value from api side.But that changes is not coming in the app side.Still loading the previous data which i got first.What will be the issue.

Comment: `But that changes is not coming in the app side.` i don't understand what you're doing, are you actually executing the call again after changing the data on the backend ? the data obviously won't just automatically change by making changes to the backend if you don't execute the call again

Comment: Do you use any local caching?